# Implementing IAuthenticationFilter, Unit of Work and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unity-container, asp.net-web-api2, unit-of-work

I have a Web API 2 project that is implementing a custom IAuthenticationFilter such as the following.

My problem is the UnitOfWork is not injected by Unity in the BasicAuthenticator class. As expected Unity successfully injects UnitOfWork in Controllers.

```
public class BasicAuthenticator : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    [Dependency]
    public UnitOfWork UoW { get; set; }

    public bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }     

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context,
                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // ignore missing implementation
        context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { id });     
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context,
                            CancellationToken cancellationToken) {}
}
```

Comment: Since the BasicAuthenticatior is an Attribute and probably used as such, there will be no DependencyInjection, since it will not be instantiated by unity but the mvc framework. You could try to get the unity container in the BasicAuthetnicator constructor.

Comment: @TGlatzer, you are right in that the framework instantiates the filter.  However, you can create a custom Filter Provider that will perform the dependency injection on the filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to create a custom `IFilterProvider` that will perform a BuildUp() on the applicable filters.  The BuildUp operation will inject all dependencies into the filter.

Here is a UnityFilterProvider that does that:

```
public class UnityFilterProvider : ActionDescriptorFilterProvider, IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public UnityFilterProvider(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public new IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(
        HttpConfiguration configuration,
        HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = base.GetFilters(configuration, actionDescriptor);

        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            container.BuildUp(filter.Instance.GetType(), filter.Instance);
        }

        return filters;
    }
}
```

Next at application startup you need to replace the default filter provider with the custom provider above:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(
    typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider),
    new UnityFilterProvider(container));

var providers = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders()
               .ToList();
var defaultprovider = providers.First(p => p is ActionDescriptorFilterProvider);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Remove(
    typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider), 
    defaultprovider);
```

I usually use the [Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET Web API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.AspNet.WebApi/) so I put the above code in the UnityConfig.cs after `RegisterTypes()`.